# Display ASPX Popup control in RowDeleteing Event (ASPX Gridview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have an ASPXGridview that includes a New and Delete button. The Delete button includs a gv_RowDeleting event. 
I want to show AspxPopupControl (ID="pupConfirm"). I want the user to have to confirm the password to delete an item. 
I tried:

```
protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
{
    pupConfirm.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
}
```

But nothing happened. Please help me. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template column with javascript to prompt for confirmation.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
                    OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')){return false;}">
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for support
But i want to show an popup (ASPX Popupcontrol) to get User to type his/her password to delete an item

Answer (score 0):

Use **Modal PopUp**. You can see code and demo here:
[Building Modal Popup using ASP.Net AJAX ModalPopupExtender Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Building-Modal-Popup-using-ASPNet-AJAX-ModalPopupExtender-Control.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, it's so beautiful Popup. But i don't know what can i use event in ASPX Gridview to use this Modal Popup  


As i see, event click on button like this:
`<asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" /> `

I think i must use customButtonclick event in ASPXGridview, right?. Thank again my friend ! @Kio Fujiwara

Comment: You can use the `modalpopup.show()` to open the modal pop up inside the button event or any event in c# code.